# Clarification about fundamental matrix of solution of a system of linear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have some doubts and things I need to be clarified about fundamental matrices of solutions of systems of linear ODEs of 1st order.

I would like to know If I multiply my Matrix $M$ to another square constant matriz $\alpha$, is this still a fundamental matrix of solution.

Which leads me to another question: with what should I identify the matrix exponential? the proper exponential matrix of solution or

$e^{A(t-t0)} = M e^{At_0}M^{-1}(t_0)$

Answer (score 2):

A fundamental matrix of solutions of the system $x' = A x$ is any square matrix $M$ of full rank (and entries that can be functions of $t$) such that $M' = A M$.  For any constant $n \times n$ matrix $B$, we do have $(MB)' = M' B = A M B$, so you can multiply $M$ by a constant matrix of full rank on the right and still have a fundamental matrix.  Different fundamental matrices can be distinguished by the initial conditions, i.e. their values at $t=0$.

I don't think I understand your second question.
If $A$ is a constant matrix, the matrix exponential $e^{At}$ is the fundamental matrix for $x' = A x$ with initial condition $M(0) = I$.

Comment: Hi Robert! Thanks for your fast and clear reply! I understood the first part entirely. The second was because I was doing an exercise wrong but now I understood. Thanks you so much!

Comment: Quick question: does that mean that the only instance that I can take $Y' = AY$ and make $Y = e^{At}$ is when the initial condition is $M(0) = I$?

Comment: Yes.  For initial condition $Y(0)=B$, the solution would be $Y = e^{At} B$.